# ensure a popover UIViewController is always on foreground

Tags: ios, xcode

From my parent controller I call a segue to a popover view which properly appears above the anchor point. The problem is that when I tap somewhere on the parent view the popover disappears and the parent view comes to the foreground. I want the popover to always remain locked in the foreground until I explicitly dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    return NO;
}
```

make sure you set the delegate to get method call

Comment: it seems that this is deprecated in iOS 9.0

Comment: self.myPopovercontroller.passthroughViews=[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.view];

try this